# merge the two vectors

Tags: c++, stl

we have to merge the two vector and i am do so but i do not get the output from the give code ...please help me to find  out the problem..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<int> v1={1,2,4,5};
  vector<int> v2={10,9,6,3};
   vector<int> v3;
   int i=0;
        for(int value1:v1)
        {
            v3[i]=value1;
            i++;
        }
        for(int value2:v2)
        {
            v3[i]=value2;
            i++;
        }
        for(int value3:v3)
        {
           cout<<value3<<" ";
        }
        
}
```

a correct code for my question

Comment: Looks like you want [`std::vector:::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: I looked at the duplicate Q&A but it doesn't seem to answer your question about what the problem with your code is. I've tried to explain it in my answer below. Does that answer your question or do you want me to clarify it further?

Answer (score 4):

`v3` is empty so `v3[i]=...;` is out of bounds. You need `v3.push_back(value)` or `v3.emplace_back(value)` to add elements to it. Example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v3;
v3.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size());

for(int value : v1) {
    v3.push_back(value);
}
for(int value : v2) {
    v3.push_back(value);
}
```

A simpler way would be to copy construct `v3` from `v1` and then use the member function `insert` to add all the elements from `v2` at the end of `v3` at once:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v3 = v1;
v3.insert(v3.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xG3sjM3x6)